# C#, Multi Threading: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, multithreading, io, access-denied

I found a problem in my multi threading application tested in windows and android,
problem is about thread lock states and working on files.
when I use lock object to open files in another thread this will works fine but when I abort the thread (I think) all of lock state will break from lock and I will get:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

I made a sample project in console application and you can test it:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
        {
            threads.Add(MakeThreadRunning());
        }
        foreach (var item in threads)
        {
            item.Abort();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("finish");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static object lockAccess = new object();
    static Thread MakeThreadRunning()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(()=>
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    lock(lockAccess)
                    {
                        using (var stream = new FileStream(@"D:\file.rar", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(100);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        });
        thread.IsBackground = false;
        thread.Start();
        return thread;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"when I abort the thread [bad things]"_ -- yup. There's a reason that any reasonably informed person will advise you to _never_ abort a thread. If you need your thread to terminate early, devise some cooperative mechanism to accomplish that.

Comment: if I don't abort my thread how break all of works? like http connections and awaitable data and etc.

Comment: Aborting your thread doesn't do anything to disconnect HTTP connections, nor awaitable data (I assume by that you mean values that will be returned in the future by some async operation). There are lots of Q&A on Stack Overflow discussing proper, cooperative termination of threads. In the modern .NET era, `CancellationTokenSource` would be a good option, especially if you are already consuming async operations that can accept a `CancellationToken`.

Comment: Also good option will be to use `Monitor class` instead of `lock` along with `finally` block as Eric Lippert explains in [his article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix/).

Comment: @cloudikka I test your case this works fine and dont show access denied problem.not good design but works.

Comment: I am not here to argue about beauty of the design. I am here to help. Mission completed.

Comment: I test again that is not working :( , I wrote a wrong code in test

Comment: I think [this](https://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation) answers your question